# jQuery inputs focused, blurred and everything inbetween

Tags: jquery, input, expand, onblur, onfocus

I have three inputs. I want them all to start and end with the same width but in the event one of them is clicked, i want that one to increase width and ALL THE OTHERS to decrease widths. Is there a way that, if one input is focused and the others are NOT focused but NOT YET blurred, I can apply a new class to the inputs?

A sort of working model can be found at: http://testserver1.staceylanehosting.net

Here is my jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('#wrapper-newsletter input[type="text"]').addClass("idleField");
$('#wrapper-newsletter input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("idleField").addClass("focusField");
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue){
        this.value = '';
    }
    if(this.value != this.defaultValue){
        this.select();
    }
});
$('#wrapper-newsletter input[type="text"]').blur(function() {
    $(this).removeClass("focusField").addClass("idleField-shrink");
    if ($.trim(this.value == '')){
        this.value = (this.defaultValue ? this.defaultValue : '');
    }
});
```

});

Here is the HTML Markup:

```
        <div id="wrapper-newsletter" class="grid_8">
    <h4>Receive Updates</h4>
    <p>To recieve notifications when our site is updated, enter your email address and name below!</p>
    <form>
        <input type="text" class="idleField" name="newsletter-name" value="Name" />
        <input type="text" class="idleField" name="newsletter-surname" value="Surname" />
        <input type="text" class="idleField" name="newsletter-email" value="Email" />
        <a href="#" title="Subscribe" class="button-blue">
            <span>Subscribe</span>
        </a>
    </form>
</div><!-- div#wrapper-newsletter -->
```

And the relevant CSS:

```
    #wrapper-newsletter input[type=text] { width: 102px; }
    .idleField { }
    .idleField-shrink{ width: 63px !important; }
    #wrapper-newsletter input[type=text]:focus { width: 180px; }
```

Comment: Trying to understand better...  Let's say all inputs start at 100px.  After clicking in the first one it should grow to, say, 120px, AND you want the non-focused inputs to shrink to say, 63px.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes! But if the user clicks out of the field, all inputs return to 100px regardless of whether or not they've been clicked.

Comment: Is there a way that I can tell the jquery that all these inputs are related and as soon as one becomes focused to apply classA to the focused elements and classB to the other elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. If you're curious to see the outcome or are here looking for the answer to the question:

http://jsfiddle.net/stacigh/q8T7r/3/

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to do mainly with css:

```
.idleField { }
.idleField-shrink{ width: 63px !important; }
.idleField-shrink:focus{ width: 120px !important; }
```

Then with onClick() you can set all inputs to the .idleField-shrink class.

Comment: This didn't work because they need to return to their original widths once all the interaction has stopped.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Although I didn't go for your exact approach, your answer did lead me in the right direction and I was able to figure out the rest on my own. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that JavaScript has any perception of difference between not-focused/not-blurred *yet* and not-focused/not-blurred. It's easy enough to achieve what you're asking just using `focus()` and `blur()`:

```
$('input').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('focused');
    }).blur(
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('focused');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/juCNj/).

If you do need to visually distinguish between elements that have, and have not, had focus/blur events, then I'd suggest using a class-name (in my example the `hasHadFocus` class):

```
$('input').focus(
    function(){
        $(this).addClass('focused');
    }).blur(
    function(){
        $(this).removeClass('focused').addClass('hasHadFocus');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/juCNj/1/).

This is only a proof-of-concept, I leave it to you to put in the specific widths you need to use.

References:

- [`focus()`](http://api.jquery.com/focus/).
- [`blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).